# Use specific Assembly for AddIn

Tags: c#, devexpress, version, .net-assembly, assemblyversions

I have created an AddIn for a existing application (C#). The AddIn uses the DevExpress-Library. My AddIn uses it too - but with a newer version. I need the newer version because there are some features which I need only available in the new version.

The applications directory-structure is:

```
app (contains all applicaiton binaries)
 - userextension
    - addin (in this directory is my addin)
```

The DevExpress-Assemblies for the application are in the app-directory. This one for my addin (with the newer version) are in the addin-directory. Now it seems that my addin is using this one which are loaded from the app (the old version assemblies). Can I configure (perhaps in the myaddin.dll.config) that myaddin.dll should always use the DevExpress-Assemblies in the addin-Directory with the correct version?

Comment: Basically you want to use different version of same dll ?

Comment: yes. But I cannot change the Host-System (existing Application). I can only change my AddIn.